# How to get Azure list storage by c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I need list of Azure storage from my subscription ID and authentication token. 
I am doing code as per reference -`

> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460787.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

But I am not able to get that data and in response I am only getting code `401 Unauthorized access`

I have tried code in c# as per below -

Get Authorization Token -

```
private static string GetAuthorizationToken()
        {
            ClientCredential cc = new ClientCredential(ClientId, ServicePrincipalPassword);
            var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/" + AzureTenantId);
            var result = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", cc);
            if (result == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
            }

            return result.Result.AccessToken;
        }
```

And then

```
AuthToken = GetAuthorizationToken();
                TokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(AuthToken);

                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://management.core.windows.net/<My Subscription ID>/services/storageservices");
                request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + AuthToken);
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Method = "GET";
                //request.Headers["Authorization"] =  "Bearer " + AuthToken; // Also tried this 
                request.Headers["x-ms-version"] =  "2016-05-31";//

                //https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/storageservices
                //header - "x-ms-version"

                HttpWebResponse response = null;
                try
                {
                    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();                    
                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {
                    //ex.Message;
                }
```

Please suggest any solution to get storage account list from Subscription ID and Authentication token. and if you have any better solution other then this to get storage list then also please suggest.

Comment: Please try by changing following line of code `var result = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", cc);` to `var result = context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", cc);`.

Comment: @GauravMantri I have tied as per you suggested but it is giving error in that authentication - An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 0):

I use the below function to create similar requests:

```
private static async Task<HttpWebRequest> createHttpRequestWithToken(Uri uri)
{
    HttpWebRequest newRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);
    string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"]);
    string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"]);
    ClientCredential creds = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OrganizationId"]));
    AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", creds);
    newRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + authResult.AccessToken);     
    return newRequest;
}
```

And create request like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = createHttpRequestWithToken(uri).Result;
```

Additionally, Windows Azure Service Management API needs to be granted permission to access the resources. This can be done in the Configure tab in AD Service Principal.

[image]

Comment: I am getting stuck on this line - AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", creds); do u have any idea why it get stuck on this line?

Comment: There is no error throwing, it just keep processing request and stay on that processing.

Comment: Apologies on the delay in replying but I recently found an issue with using "await" causing a deadlock http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html . Could you try using  AuthenticationResult authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", creds).ConfigureAwait(false);

Answer (score 0):

To [list all the storage accounts available under the subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts#StorageAccounts_List), you could try to use:

> GET /subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts?api-version=2016-01-01

the following sample code works fine on my side, please refer to it.

```
string tenantId = "xxxx";
string clientId = "xxxx";
string clientSecret = "xxxx";
string subscriptionid = "xxxx";

string authContextURL = "https://login.windows.net/" + tenantId;
var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContextURL);
var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
var result = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource: "https://management.azure.com/", clientCredential: credential);

if (result == null)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
}

string token = result.AccessToken;
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts?api-version=2016-01-01", subscriptionid));

request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers["Authorization"] =  "Bearer " + token; 


HttpWebResponse response = null;
try
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    //ex.Message;
}
```

response in fiddler looks like this.

[image]

Besides, please make sure if you [assign the application to a role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role), if not assign the application to a role, 403 error will appear.